# Ansible: How to recursively set directory and file permissions

Tags: file-permissions, ansible

In ansible, I can do this:

```
file: dest=/foo/bar/somedir owner=root group=apache mode=0775 recurse=yes
```

And it recursively sets the owner, group, and permissions to 0775 on all directories and files in that path. But I want to set directories to 0775, and files to 0664. Is there some way to make ansible do this?

Comment: Related:  [Change all folder permissions  with one command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/349053/23408#349063).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
file: dest=/foo/bar/somedir owner=root group=apache mode=u=rwX,g=rX,o=rX recurse=yes
```

will set directories to 755, and files to 644.

Comment: this does not work for files.

Comment: @Adam Chance Where is the magic? How does specifying u,g,o make it different than the number (and where is 644 written?)

Comment: The source code mentions that the symbolic u.g.o handling is the same as "man chmod"'s handling -- capital X has special handling based on the dir/file status and existing execute bits. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/8606fb33f0e8954b588eaecec2d99b4a120fd4ad/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py#L1419-L1421

Comment: In other words, `X` is `x` for directories, and nothing for files. And that's how [`chmod`](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/core/coreutils/chmod.1.en), not `ansible` treats the mode string. I wish `S` would be treated likewise.

Comment: But do note, that it makes files executable by owner executable by [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778738/ansible-mode-755-for-directories-and-644-for-files-recursively#comment95518029_29793833).

Answer (score 35):

> The Ansible file/copy modules don't give you the granularity of
>   specifying permissions based on file type so you'd most likely need to
>   do this manually by doing something along these lines:
>
> ```
> - name: Ensure directories are 0755
>   command: find {{ path }} -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
>
> - name: Ensure files are 0644
>   command: find {{ path }} -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
> ```
>
> These would have the effect of recursing through `{{ path }}` and
>   changing the permissions of every file or directory to the specified
>   permissions.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28782805/1306186

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use the module file in ansible, you can:

> file: dest=/foo/bar/somedir owner=root group=apache mode=0644 recurse=yes
>
> file: dest=/foo/bar/somedir owner=root group=apache mode=0775

With this method you first set all the file (recurse=yes) to '644' and then you set /foo/bar/somedir to '775'.

This is not perfect because it will change your directory permission each time you play your playbook.
But at least it is idempotent, not like the module command.

If you don't want to have 'changed' status, you can use the module stat. It will list all the files and directory in  /foo/bar/somedir so you register the answer and then make a loop on those files only.

Comment: Your answer will set all subfiles and subdirectories to 644, while setting only the top-level directory to 775. The need is for all *directories* to be 775, including subdirectories.

Comment: This suggestion is not idempotent. Setting permissions first to one value, and later to another, means that the permissions will be changed on every run.

Comment: This is idempotent - the state is the same if run multiple times.  Idempotent != no changes.

Comment: @Geoff that's questionable since each task should ideally be idempotent, not just the playbook. In this case these tasks individually would not be idempotent. If you were to use `register` with these tasks to check for changes, those tasks would always be triggered.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure how much sense it would be to set directories to 0775 (`rwxrwxr-x`) and files to 0644 (`rw-r--r--`): group-writeable directories but not files?

If you meant to set files to 0664 (`rw-rw-r--`) to ensure that files are not executable while directories are traversable then there is an elegant solution involving only one `chmod` command:

```
chmod -c -R ug=rw,o=r,a-x+X "{{top_dir}}"
```

Here is how it can be used in *Ansible*:

```
- name: recursive chmod example
  command: |
    chmod -c -R ug=rw,o=r,a-x+X "{{item}}"
  register: chmod_status
  changed_when: chmod_status.stdout != ""
  with_items:
    - "/home/user/sample/dir"
```

`chmod -c` prints all the changes that we can conveniently use to populate "changed" status in *Ansible*. I hope it make sense.

Answer (score 6):

To only change mods when needed:

```
- name: make dirs 0755   
  command: find {{ your_path }} -type d ! -perm 0755 -exec chmod 0755 {} \;

- name: make files 0644   
  command: find {{ your_path }} -type f ! -perm 0644 -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use copy: module and set the directory_mode to 0755 and mode to 644 for files.  Note that you need the forward slash "/" at the end for recursive copying.

Example:

```
    - name: Recursively copy testing directory
      copy:
        src: testing/
        dest: /opt/testing/
        directory_mode: 0755
        owner: test
        group: test
        mode: 0644
```

Answer (score 3):

```
- name: Change permissions on /remote/file/path to ansible:user so we can write to it 
  file:
    path: /remote/file/path/(or file)
    owner: root (or other)
    # recursive if you need it
    # recurse:true 
    group: users (or other)
    mode: "0770"
```

Or, making more 'Ansible-ish' the appreciated answer above

```
 name: Change permissions from /SM/data-drive/sm_sites etc...
  file:
    dest: "{{ item }}"
    owner: www-data
    group: www-data    
    recurse: true 
    # supposed to set directories to 755 and files to 644
    mode: u=rwX,g=rX,o=rX
  with_items:
    - /SM/data-drive/sm_sites
    - /SM/data-drive/smw_dams
    - /SM/data-drive/smw_wikis
```

Answer (score 2):

A more modern approach would be to first **filter out** the dirs like so:

```
  - name: Evaluating home dirs    
    find:    
      path: "/home"    
      file_type: "directory"    
    register: homedirs    

  # This returns the actual dir-path's 
  - set_fact: 
      homes: "{{ homedirs.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"           

  - name: Changing permissions of /home/*
    file:    
      path: "{{ item }}"  
      mode: 0700  
    with_items:    
      - "{{ homes }}"
```

**NOTE:**  Change "file_type" parameter to "file", for files to be affected

Answer (score 1):

As an example, as if "securing" a hypothetical Joomla! instance:

```
- name: Ensure to secure the Joomla installation
  shell: "find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \\; && find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \\; && chown -R www-data: cache modules images media modules logs tmp administrator/cache"
  args:
      chdir: "{{ production_backend_root_path }}"
  tags: 
      - joomla_secure
```

Where root owns all but a few designated directories owned by the webserver.